# What is a proscriptive linguist?

Tags: meaning

In the New York Review of Books, Martin Amis is quoted as saying that Trump's "extemporizing idiolect," is "an adventure playground for any proscriptive linguist." What is a proscriptive linguist? Is it a formal occupation? Are there any nearby?

Comment: It sounds like someone who tries to ban language. Are you sure the term wasn't "prescriptive linguist"?

Comment: *Proscriptive* tells you what not to do, *prescriptive* tells you what to do, and *descriptive* tells you what has been done.

Answer (score 1):

This is very interesting as it’s actually an error. What they mean is “prescriptive linguist”. I’ve actually seen this before where an author has used the word proscriptive and it hasn’t been corrected by the editor.

A prescriptive linguist is someone who attempts to create rules and standards of the English language. Most editors, proofreaders, style-guide writers and authors of books about the rules of English would be classed as prescriptive linguists.

Of course, some people would argue that English is always changing, and it is! You only need to read texts from previous centuries to see this. The classic opposite to a prescriptive linguist is a **descriptive** linguist. They look at English how it is actually used in practice - in speech, in texts, in any setting, and say “it is effectively correct because that is how it is being used.” A linguistic researcher may be described as a descriptive linguist, or even the people who add words to the dictionary. After a word becomes extremely commonly used by a large number of people, it may be granted entry to the dictionary. For example, the word irregardless is now in the dictionary, but a prescriptive linguist would say the word is nonsense, as the more “correct” word is  **regardless**. A descriptive linguist would say it is ok, as it’s a word that many thousands of people *use*.

Even prescriptive linguists have to allow for descriptivism sometimes. For example, once a “correct” syntax decreases in common usage and a new syntax becomes almost, as or more common, they may decide to add it to their grammar rules. “I wish I was God” would have once been defined as incorrect by English by prescriptivists. Traditionally the subjunctive mood uses “were” in place of “was”, so the more correct form is “I wish I were God”. But most would agree now that both are usable.

Now you can understand the excerpt from the article. It seems to me to suggest that Trump’s words (“extemporizing” means “lacking preparation” or “thoughtless” and “idiolect” means the language/words used by an individual) contain many spelling, punctuation and grammatical errors - at least according to the standard rules prescriptive linguists have tried to create! There are so many that they form an “adventure playground” for people looking to make corrections!

Also note how using proscriptive instead of prescriptive is an ironic prescriptive error! Proscriptive means “relating to proscription” and proscription means a ban or prohibition.

Comment: The article is "Downhill Racing: in the September 27, 2018, issue of NYRB, and it's a quote from Amis's "The Rub of Time: Bellow, Nabokov, Hitchens, Travolta, Trump: Essays and Reportage , 1994-2017. The quote definitely says "proscriptive linguist." However, Amis is known for his acid wit, and he may be just playing with "prescriptive."

Comment: @Zan700, oh dear. Amis can always defend behind this excuse!